# Communication problems using libusb library

Tags: linux, usb

I'm writing a console program to communicate with a USB device using libusb functions.
The device is correctly enumerated and it has two end-points:

```
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
    bInterval               0
```

I try to send 3 bytes by the bulk function:

```
dump( cmdPrinter, nCmdSize, "[usbxsfer] OUT:");
    
ret = libusb_bulk_transfer( devHandle, EP_OUT, 
            (unsigned char*)&cmdPrinter, nCmdSize, &wrote, timeout);
LOG4("[usbxsfer] OUT[x%02X] ret: %d - wrote: %d - pcksize=%d\n", 
    EP_OUT, ret, wrote, nCmdSize);
```

and read the reply by:

```
int toRead = 10;
ret = libusb_bulk_transfer(devHandle, EP_IN, (unsigned char*)bufferRx+offs, toRead, &xferred, timeout);
LOG2("[usbxsfer] IN ret: %d - xferred: %d\n", ret, xferred);
```

The device does not execute the command (eject some labels) and does not reply (error -7 = timeout (3 seconds)).

I installed `tshark` to sniff the bytes on the cable and tried to send '1D E0 0F' bytes.
The catpure is:

```
Frame 3: 67 bytes on wire (536 bits), 67 bytes captured (536 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (usbmon0)
        Interface name: usbmon0
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with Linux header and padding (115)
    Arrival Time: Aug 26, 2022 18:11:55.083144000 CEST
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1661530315.083144000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001053000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001053000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.001211000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 3
    Frame Length: 67 bytes (536 bits)
    Capture Length: 67 bytes (536 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb]
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 5.6.2]
    URB id: 0xffffffc0774cfe40
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_BULK (0x03)
    Endpoint: 0x02, Direction: OUT
        0... .... = Direction: OUT (0)
        .... 0010 = Endpoint number: 2
    Device: 6
    URB bus id: 5
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: present (0)
    URB sec: 1661530315
    URB usec: 83144
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 3
    Data length [bytes]: 3
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 0
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
Leftover Capture Data: d8abcb

0000  40 fe 4c 77 c0 ff ff ff 53 03 02 06 05 00 2d 00   @.Lw....S.....-.
0010  cb f0 08 63 00 00 00 00 c8 44 01 00 8d ff ff ff   ...c.....D......
0020  03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0040  d8 ab cb                                          ...
```

This should be the first packet sent to the device and in the buffer I don't see my bytes!
Anyway the result is good (worte=3) and 3 bytes are sent:

```
[2022-08-26 18:11:55] [usbxsfer] devHandle: 0x55a8dbdac0, nCmdSize: 3
[2022-08-26 18:11:55] [usbxsfer] OUT: [3] 1D E0 0F
[2022-08-26 18:11:55] [usbxsfer] OUT[x02] ret: 0 - wrote: 3 - pcksize=3
```

The buffer seems to be correct but that data is not present in the buffer: maybe this is the reason why the command is not executed (and not replied).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!

The problem was in libusb_bulk_transfer() call where I passed the pointer of a pointer :(

The correct code is:

```
ret = libusb_bulk_transfer( devHandle, EP_OUT, 
        (unsigned char*)cmdPrinter, nCmdSize, &wrote, timeout);
```

Now I see the data end the commands are executed.